# Express and Body-Parser not returning values

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I am new to nodejs and express in general. I am trying to get a POST value from a html page using body-parser. I tried following several suggestions in SO but unable to make it work for me.

Here is the code. Any pointers will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Server.js

```
    var express = require('express');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var Subscribe = require('./models/subscribe');

    mongoose.connect('CREDENTIALS');

    var app = express();

    app.use(bodyParser.json(), bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

    var port = 3000;

    var router = express.Router();

    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
      res.json({ message: 'Test...' });
    });

    var subscribeRoute = router.route('/subscribe');
    subscribeRoute.post(function(req, res) {
      var subscribe = new Subscribe();

      subscribe.email = req.body.email_notify;
      console.log(subscribe);

      subscribe.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
            res.status(500).send(err);

        res.status(200);
      });
    });

    app.use('/api', router);
    app.listen(port);
```

index.html

```
    <form action="http://localhost:3000/api/subscribe/" method="POST" enctype="application/json">
    <input type="text" onfocus="if (this.value=='E-mail Address') this.value = ''" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'E-mail Address'" value="E-mail Address" id="email_notify" name="email_notify" />
    <button id="notify_me" ontouchstart="">Notify Me!</button><br/>
    </form>
```

Thanks
Sujith

Comment: you are not submitting your form...

Answer (score -1):

Make `<input type='submit'>` instead of the `<button>` and remove `enctype` form the form.

Also in Chrome open developer tools, network tab and check that the request is sent to your server at all

Comment: The form will be submited with a button

Comment: Hi. I am submitting the form using jquery post.... Anyway i tried changing to input type submit but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: If it works with postman than its something wrong with your form submission. Try to remove 'enctype' from the form. P.S. Can somebody explain why the answer is downvoted?

Comment: And add your js script which is posting the form and also the subscriber.js

Answer (score -1):

change this

```
app.use(bodyParser.json(), bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

To this

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Comment: Thanks Stalin. This doesn't work either. The application somehow works when i use Postman/Rest Easy. So i am guessing that there is some issue with the html file?